# So it's like a dice roll game and like I'm getting stuck on a loop and I'm not sure how to fix it

Tags: loops, while-loop, dice

It keeps messing up on the loop it either does nothing, does the command over and over, or does it twice? These are just things that happen when I tried to do it myself

reapting an if statement, adding a while, finding a random related thing I thought would help.
the code
import random
import time

```
ans=input("Do you roll a dice? Y/N ")
if ans in ("N", "n"):
    print("Then when did you click this game?")
else:
    dr=random.choice("123456")
    time.sleep(1.7)
    print("You got a "+dr)
again = input("Do you want to roll again? Y/N ")
while again in ("y", "Y"):
           dr=random.choice("123456")
time.sleep(1.7)`
print("You got a "+dr)
again = input("Do you want to roll again? Y/N ")
```